# Add Gem WDM to GemFile in Git Never works

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, middleman

I am trying to use [Middleman](https://middlemanapp.com) to create a website, and I am running into a lot of issues with trying to do it. To solve these issues I am currently running ruby through the git interface to resolve several errors that I get when trying to do this by other methods (like cmd). Right now I am having an issue getting the first step in doing a website with Middleman and getting errors when executing the first command in the first step of the [tutorial](https://middlemanapp.com/basics/start-new-site).

I have found no resolution to my problem of WDM not working at all. Here is an image of what happens when I try to execute the command `middleman init`. After getting this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75G40.png) I run `bundle install` and try again and get this [Amazing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeFND.png) that I have found no source in finding out how to fix. When I Do `gem install WDM -v '0.1.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` it [seems to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70SE4.png) but then spits out the same error when I run `middleman init` again. I have no idea why this is happening when I can find no other sources on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running the suggested command at the bottom

```
gem install wdm -v '0.1.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

?

Comment: when I run `gem install wdm -v '0.1.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` it says `$ gem install wdm -v '0.1.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions.  
This could take a while...
Successfully installed WDM-0.1.1
Parsing documentation for WDM-0.1.1
Done installing documentation for WDM after 0 seconds
1 gem installed` 
and then I get the second error that I mentioned before.[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeFND.png) Forgot to put that in my question.